# Ability to 'Hide' a site pending implementation in SharePoint 2007

Tags: site-settings

All,

I've a new site which has been developed on a Test Site (copy of Production) which is due to be launched / implemented on the Prodcution Site.

My knowledge/ ability within SharePoint 2007 is limited and I maintain the site mainly through 'Rich Text' editing.

Is it possible to create a site (accessed via the Global Navigation Bar) but hidden from view pending it's launch, whereby it will then become visible?

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on MOSS 2007 and not WSS 3.0, to accomplish this there are two steps you need to take:

1. Set up the new site with limited permissions so that only the users who are working on it while its being created can access this site. This will make it so that anywhere SharePoint would enumerate a list of all the sites and will prevent anyone without access from getting in from a hyperlink or by typing in the URL.
2. Set up the global navigation link with audience targeting. Audience targeting is a feature that when implemented will only show the navigation item. The reason you have to be on MOSS for this is because you need to have the Publishing Infrastructure site collection feature enabled. This turns your "Top Navigation" and "Quick Launch" settings into a unified "Navigation" setting with more options available to you including the audience targeting feature. Once this is set up,  only the groups specified as the audience will be able to see the top navigation link.